# Android Chrome corrupts soft keyboard area after returning from Facebook dialog

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, iframe, android-softkeyboard

Environment: Mobile (Galaxy), Android, Chrome. I have a parent website and an iframe on top of it, which covers the **whole** screen (with large z-index).

On clicking a button in the iframe, I call a facebook 'Share' dialog, which works **great**... except that after returning from the dialog, the rectangular space at the bottom, which used to hold the soft keyboard, now shows the parent background website, thus cropping the iframe in the middle. Even refresh doesn't change that.

The only ugly workaround I've found is: After returning from facebook dialog, add a click event wherever, which invokes a function that temporarily reveals and hides the soft keyboard (using one of the many examples that focus on some dummy input text field).

Here is the essence of the iframe code. Nothing special. Note same code does **not** produce this problem on an iPhone or on a Nexus I also tested.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body dir="rtl">

<div style="display:block;">
  <img src="sharfb.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="fbShareDialog();" />
</div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId  : '.......',
      status : false,
      cookie : false,
      xfbml  : true,
      frictionlessRequests : true});
  };

  (function(){
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
     var fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     var js = document.createElement('script');
     js.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
     js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js';
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }());

  function fbShareDialog() {
    var params = {method: 'share', href: 'http://www.example.com'};
    FB.ui(params, function(response){;});
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is always reproducible, then I would recommend creating a bug with the relevant repro steps at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @free-bud Did you ever find a solution to this? Seems to happen on the FB login dialog as well.

Comment: No... but I stopped looking. Note the [not-so-nice] workaround I'm using, in my original post.